# Enable anonymous Access (svnserv)

Tags: svn, authentication

Some time ago I set up a Svn Repository (svnserv as far as I remember), using svn+ssh for authentication. As I finally want to switch to Git on Github now, I want to enable public access to let Github do the import stuff.

As it seems like I've lost the Setup documentation, I'd like to know how to enable public access for the Repository.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can configure this in the file `conf/svnserve.conf` in the svn repository folder. See also http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s03.html for details.